# Given a series of sequences of events at certain times, how can I calculate the degree of similarity / dissimilarity?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, similarities

I'm analysing a series of feature analyses for live music, where identified segments or key changes are associated with a given timestamp, i.e:

```
((C Minor, 0.00), (D Minor, 5.00), (C Minor 50.00))    
((C Minor, 2.00), (D Minor, 4.00), (C Minor 50.00))   
((C Minor, 6.00), (D Minor, 14.00), (D Minor 80.00))
```

etc. etc.

How can I calculate the average differentiation or skew between the sets? I'm trying to find a way to see if a particular track differs from the other dramatically, but lack the mathematical knowledge to devise a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you'd use an RNN to learn to classify the sequences. So, convert each timestep of your input data into some features, eg 1-hot over the pitch, or similar. Feed the input data for each timestep into an RNN. Put a classifier over the final hidden state of the RNN (you should probably use the 'LSTM' form of an RNN by the way). Train your network :)